# How to perform round to even with floating point numbers

Tags: floating-point, binary, rounding, ieee-754

In regards to IEEE-754 single precision floating point, how do you perform round to nearest, where ties round to the nearest even digit in the required position (the default and by far the most common mode)?

Basically I have the guard bit, round bit, and sticky bit.
So if we form those into a vector and call it GRS, then the following rules apply:

1. If `G = 0`, round down (do nothing)
2. If `G = 1`, and `RS == 10` or `RS == 01`, round up (add one to mantissa)
3. if `GSR = 111`, round to even

So I am not sure how to perform the round to nearest.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Just to make sure we're on the same page, `G` is the most significant bit of the three, `R` comes next and `S` can be thought of as the least significant bit because its value partially represents the even less significant bits that have been truncated in the calculations. These three bits are only used while doing calculations and aren't stored in the floating-point variable before or after the calculations.

This is what you should do in order to round the result to the nearest even number using `G`, `R` and `S`:

**GRS** - Action
**0xx** - round down = do nothing (x means any bit value, 0 or 1)
**100** - this is a **tie**: round up if the mantissa's bit just before **G** is 1, else round down=do nothing
**101** - round up
**110** - round up
**111** - round up

Rounding up is done by adding 1 to the mantissa in the mantissa's least significant bit position just before `G`. If the mantissa overflows (its 23 least significant bits that you will store become zeroes), you have to add 1 to the exponent. If the exponent overflows, you set the number to +infinity or -infinity depending on the number's sign.

In the case of a tie, you add 1 to the mantissa if the mantissa is odd and you add nothing if it's even. That's what makes the result rounded to the nearest even value.

Comment: Do you even need the round bit?  Can't you just look at the guard bit and the sticky bit becomes the OR of the round and old sticky bit?

Comment: You may use none of these bits if you aren't very concerned about rounding. They just help you get a more accurate result.

Comment: well I am concerned about rounding, so does my comment "Can't you just look at the guard bit and the sticky bit becomes the OR of the round and old sticky bit?" make sense?

Comment: It does not. The sticky bit does not depend on what's to the left of it, it depends on what gets into it or past it to the right.

Comment: Could you explain how that table(GRS action) is derived? Or any material and link would be useful.

Comment: @inherithandle See, for example, the `On Rounding` section of this [page](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~cs354-1/cs354/karen.notes/flpt.apprec.html).

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze, that link is broken. Do you have another reference? Thanks

Comment: @Veridian [wayback machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20130124022505/http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~cs354-1/cs354/karen.notes/flpt.apprec.html) ?

Comment: @Veridian your observation “can't you just look at the guard bit and the sticky bit becomes the OR of the round and old sticky bit” is absolutely correct in the case you presented, and indeed the round bit is not necessary. *However*, it is required in the case of subtractions, when the result underflows and needs to be shifted left. When that happens, a third bit is needed to decide what to do in the tie case.

Comment: In case it is 011, I think you also need to round up?

Comment: @Aaron No. What you're suggesting is like rounding 0.375 to an integer, that is, up to 1 (or 1.375 up to 2).

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze I think you are wrong. If we have 011, that means we want to place the "point" between the 0 and 11 (0.11). The first one means that the value behind the point is >= 0.5 and the second 1 means that it is actually > 0.5, so we round up. (the first bit after the point is 2^(-1) = 0.5)

Comment: @Aaron The GRS bits are used to round the result and then they are discarded. So, the "point" is here: result_mantissa.GRS and not here: result_mantissaG.RS.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze it seems that there are two ways of doing this... I clarified my answer accordingly. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @Aaron But conceptually there's no difference. You look at the bits you're going to discard (3 or 2) and the tie case and all other cases are still there and they are handled the same way.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze of course, the outcome and the underlying mathematical reasoning is the same, but it is a different way of getting to the result. So maybe some prefer one over the other way :)

Answer (score 10):

Just wanted to add that **S** bit is not just a bit following **GR** bits. If there are bits available *after* **GRS** bits, it actually is a logical **OR** of those, including **S** bit.
 
In other words, if there is any bit following **GR** bits that is **1** then the **S** bit value will be **1**.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following for rounding when you have a set of bits lower than the precision you are keeping:

1. If the least significant bit you are keeping is 0, just add 0x7ff....f to rounding bits.
2. If the least significant bit you are keeping is 1, just add 0x800....0 to rounding bits.

I think this implements the desired behavior doing only one test.

Answer (score 0):

These are the rules for rounding to even based on the guard, round and sticky bit (INCR Yes/No signifies whether to add or not add a 1).

| GRS | INCR |
| --- | --- |
| x0x | N |
| 010 | N |
| 110 | Y |
| x11 | Y |

The two interesting cases are the ones with x10, because then we have the situation where we need to round to even. An even binary number has a 0 in the least significant bit, and we can only increment the number or leave it as it is. So to make it even (get a zero at the least significant bit) in case of x10, if the guard is 0 we leave it and if it is 1 we increment.

EDIT:
Apparently, there are two variations to this. Either the guard bit is the least significant bit that is kept, or it is the most significant bit that is cut off. My answer uses the guard bit as the least significant bit that is kept, so it is: result_mantissaG.RS. My source for this is the course [Systems Programming](https://systems.ethz.ch/education/courses/2022-autumn-semester/systems-programming-and-computer-architecture-.html) at ETH Zurich by [Prof. Roscoe](https://systems.ethz.ch/people/profile.timothy-roscoe.html):

[image: lecture slide]